# Bash Switch Statement and Executing Multiple Programs

Tags: linux, bash, switch-statement

I'm trying to use a Bash `switch` statement to execute a set of programs. The programs are run through the terminal via a script. The simple idea is ::

> In the terminal : ./shell.sh 
>   Program asks : "What number?" 
>   I input : 1

Program processes as:

```
prog="1"
case $prog in
1) exec gimp && exec mirage ;;
esac
```

I've tried it several ways yet nothing will run the second program and free the terminal. The first program runs fine and frees the terminal after closing. What am I to put after executing the first program that will allow the second to run in tandem with the first and also free the terminal?

Comment: That did it. Though now I get output to the terminal from the running programs even though I do 2&>1 /dev/null after the first command. In fact, it causes some programs to think they're running the upper command, which is weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run two commands in the background, use `&` after each of them:

```
case $prog in 
    1)  
        gimp &
        mirage &
        ;;
esac
```

`exec` basically means "start running this program instead of continuing with this script"

Comment: I up voted this because It technically works. My particular program can't do individual lines and when run on it flat doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by "can't do individual lines"? You can write `gimp & mirage &` on one line if you really want, but it makes no difference to bash.

Comment: Tell that to my bash I guess.  I did exactly that and it more or less does what my issue has been but this time it "kinda" launched the program. It just comes out garbled. Where as when I did 1) gimp & mirage ;; it worked.